# Why Swift bridging header gives syntax error sometimes after build with Xcode 7.3?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode7.3

MyApp-Swift.h header class gives me this error sometimes after rebuild, it does not happen always. I fix it by adding "//" but i do not know why it has this error.

this is the error:

[image: error code]

original code:

[image: original code]

Comment: I can see a single back slash which should give you an error

Comment: Yes i know, but i dont even touch the code, it happens itself :) its funny

Comment: is it being copied from a comment in your code?

Comment: After the build sometimes comment lines // removed itself.I have to add myself then its ok, but few builds later it happens again.

Answer (score 3):

The Obj-C header generated from Swift modules has some issues with [documentation comments](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/index.html) like `/// - Note: ...` etc. I would suggest **removing `/// Recommended`** from your Swift code, because Xcode seems to be getting confused by this, treating it like `/// - Recommended: ...` (you can see details about this specific one in the latest [Xcode release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html)).

You can also [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com) against Xcode.

Comment: It didn't work. I removed it few builds later the comment came back :)

Comment: Yes i removed that comment line from MyApp-Swift.h header file

Comment: No, you need to remove it *from your `.swift` file*.

Comment: My project is Obj-C based. And this code is inside .h file

Comment: The MyApp-Swift.h header file would not exist if there weren't some Swift code in the project. Where is CryptoExportImportManager implemented?